# Corrupted data from terminal to Host

Tags: tcpip, hosts, c#

Ive got a terminal which sends data to a host that is wrapped with `<stx>` and `<etx>`. 
However when it enters the network it always has 5/6 bytes of junk data in place of the `<stx>` and the first few expected bytes which incidentally are all zeros.

More often than not a `<CAN>` appears where I would expect the `<STX>`.
There is no reason to doubt the network and the terminal is brand new. But I would reckon that the fault is on the terminal side. Anybody see anything like this before and how can I trouble shoot it?

Comment: Needs more information. How does the terminal connect: TCP/IP, serial port etc...? What is the model of the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

> how can I trouble shoot it

If you haven't already done so, use network monitoring / capture tools at both ends and compare results.

- wireshark
- tcpdump
- Windows netmon

If there's any difference then something in the network and/or network drivers is to blame. Bear in mind that packets can be legitimately split during transit.

(My money is on a bug in some C# code)

Comment: Thank you. I guess Im looking for some reassurance re the C#